# How to allow all ports in an origin

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a nodejs server, and i use `cors` to let my client connect to me.

```
app.use(cors({origin:["http://localhost:3000"]})
```

I want to allow localhost:1000 or localhost:2000 or 4000,
I want it to let `localhost` to connect no matter what the port is.
How can i do it?

Answer (score 2):

See [the documentation](https://github.com/expressjs/cors#configuring-cors-w-dynamic-origin).

You can pass a function as the value of `origin`.

> ```
>   origin: function (origin, callback) {
>     if (whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1) {
>       callback(null, true)
>     } else {
>       callback(new Error('Not allowed by CORS'))
>     }   }
> ```

Just replace `whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1` with a regular expression or substring test that matches `http://localhost/`, optionally followed by any port.

e.g.

```
origin.substring(0, 17) === "http://localhost/";
```